# Can't run a C# web API in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run a web API written in C#,in Visual Studio code 2022 but I keep getting this error

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: Did you install the .net 6 development sdk? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: Yes,I did install the .net 6 development sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same error, it turned out Visual Studio just needed an update.

Updated it and restarted the app and it went away.